# How do door-less refrigerators keep cool air inside?

Tags: thermodynamics

I got curious when I saw a door-less refrigerator for the first time. It was in a shop and I couldn't control myself so I began to look around to see how they work but I couldn't figure it out.

They worked well and there was nothing special about them -at least I couldn't find nothing. I couldn't also feel any notable air flow trough them. There was both horizontals and verticals. Keeping cool air in a vertical fridge is more or less like keeping water in a cubic glass that has one side removed!

I wanted to google a bit but I had no keywords for that. I tried inputs like "doorless fridges" or "no door fridges" but no good result.

Comment: [Something like this](http://img.diytrade.com/smimg/1227583/13555435-2115356-0/Supermarket_Display_Merchandiser/2400.jpg)?

Comment: Yes, @KyleKanos. Exactly.

Comment: They use what's called an air-curtain to contain the colder air behind a turbulent barrier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cold air does flow down, but instead of flowing out of the fridge it is sucked into a channel, and pumped back out at the top of the fridge.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Of course, the keyword "Air Curtain" might be useful for future visitors -Thanks to @user6972.